# What's the correct way to handle uninstantiated class variables in Scala?

Tags: scala, libgdx

So, Scala deviates from Java in the way that it handles fields.  The Java way is to define them, then instantiate them in the constructor.  As I understand it, Scala does both in the constructor.  However, I'm extending a Java class that does things quite differently, as part of the game development framework LibGDX.  My code looks something like this:

```
class HelloWorld extends Game {
  private var batch: SpriteBatch = null
  private var font: BitmapFont = null

  override def create(): Unit = {
     batch = new SpriteBatch
     font = new BitmapFont
     font.setColor(Color.RED)
  }

  override def dispose(): Unit = {
    batch.dispose()
    font.dispose()
  }

  override def render(): Unit = { 
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    batch.begin()
    font.draw(batch, "Hello, world!", 200, 200)
    batch.end()
  }
}
```

Because the class has no true constructor and is instead created using `create`, I can't make variables in `create` and have them visible to other methods, leading to me to how I've done it here.  However, this forces me to use vars when they should really be vals.  Am I missing something?  Is there a better way to do this, or since I'm working with a Java-specific framework it *has* to be wonky?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I can't do something like

```
private val batch = new SpriteBatch
```

because you can't call LibGDX's object constructors until after it's initialised itself (and can subsequently call `create`).

Comment: I think it is not a shame that they are `var`, since you don't let them be modified from the outside. (besides once through `create`). Have you thought about making them `lazy vals`? e.g `private lazy val batch = new SpriteBatch`

Comment: +1 for `lazy vals`. And if you really need mutable state, you can wrap it into `Option` `private var batch: Option[SpriteBatch] = None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can write a more Scala-friendly wrapper around the Java API?

```
trait ScalaGame {
  def dispose()
  def render()
}

class GameWrapper(createGame: => ScalaGame) extends Game {
  lazy val game = createGame
  override def create() { game }
  override def dispose() = game.dispose()
  override def render() = game.render()
}
```

And then:

```
class HelloWorld extends ScalaGame {

  private val batch: SpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch
  private val font: BitmapFont = new BitmapFont
  font.setColor(Color.RED)

  override def dispose(): Unit = {
    batch.dispose()
    font.dispose()
  }

  override def render(): Unit = {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    batch.begin()
    font.draw(batch, "Hello, world!", 200, 200)
    batch.end()
  }
}

val game = new GameWrapper(new HelloWorld)
```

Comment: This is a really cool idea (and I learnt stuff about the language!) but sadly it's not working for me.  It won't compile ("'val' parameters may not be call-by-name"), so I can change it to not be call-by-name, but then it instantiates before LibGDX has initialised and it fails at runtime.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't actually test this. Edited the answer - I think it works now? I made `ScalaGame` no longer a case class, so it shouldn't be a `val` parameter now.